# In rainy days John is late $30\%$ of the time. In non rainy, $10\%$. There is a $70\%$ chance it will rain.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

> In rainy days, John is late for work with a probability of $0.3$. In non
>   rainy days, he is late with a probability of $0.1$ There is a $0.7$
>   probability that it will rain tomorrow. Determine the probability that
>   John won't be late for work tomorrow.

What I need is:

$$P(\lnot L|R) = \frac{P(\lnot L\cap R)}{P(R)}$$

I know $P(R) = 0.7$.

I also have

$$P(L|R)= 0.3\\
P(L|\lnot R)=0.1 \\
$$

From this I can find

$$P(L|R)=\frac{P(L\cap R)}{P(R)} \Leftrightarrow 0.3=\frac{P(L\cap R)}{0.7}\Leftrightarrow P(L\cap R) = .21$$

$$P(L|\lnot R) = \frac{P(L \cap \lnot R)}{P(\lnot R)}\Leftrightarrow0.1 = \frac{P(L \cap \lnot R)}{0.3}\Leftrightarrow P(L \cap \lnot R) = 0.03$$

So the probability of him being late should be $.21+.03=.24$. Then $P(\lnot L) = 0.76$. 
What is $P(\lnot L \cap R)$? I feel like I made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: $P(\neg L\mid R)+P(L\mid R)= 1$

Comment: In any case, this should have been able to be done in one line by the law of total probability and multiplication principle.  $P(L) = P(L\cap R)+P(L\cap R^c) = P(R)P(L\mid R)+P(R^c)P(L\mid R^c) = 0.7\cdot 0.3 + 0.3\cdot 0.1$

Comment: @JMoravitz So what I want is the probability of him not being late, or $1-P(L)$, and not $P(\lnot L | R)$?

Comment: Yes... you just want $1-P(L)$.  Regardless, $P(\neg L\mid R)$ or however you want to write it was effectively given in the problem statement already as being $0.7$, (1 minus the probability that he is late given it was raining)

Comment: @JMoravitz This problem is really confusing. Thanks.

Comment: As an aside, I hadn't caught this typo before when first reading, but your question title doesn't match the problem statement.  A probability of $0.1$, something happening one in ten, is different than a probability of $0.1\%$, something happening one in a thousand.

Comment: Another useful approach consists in drawing a tree diagram, though I don't know how to do it on math.se.

Answer (score 0):

Not so terribly confusing if you try **thinking** rather than just applying formulas!

Imagine this happening 10000 days.  70% of the time, 7000 days, it rains.  The other 3000 days it does not rain.  Of the 7000 days when it rains, John is late 70% of the time, 4900 days, on time the other 2100 days.  Of the 3000 days when it does not rain, John is late 0.1% of the time, 3 days, not late the other 2997 days.

So of the entire 10000 days John is late 4903 days or 49.3% of the time.

Comment: I do like this approach to such problems, when it's confusing for a student, but: OP *is* thinking (much as we often ask them to!).  They may not be thinking effectively for this problem, but it seems a bit much to imply they aren't thinking...

Comment: "*of the 7000 days when it rains, John is late 70% of the time.*"  You have a typo here.  Of the days it rains he is late 30% of the time, not 70%.